# Linking from page A to a specific iframe on page B

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm in the process of setting up a website to showcase our photographs.

For this we are using a third party supplier providing a gallery: http://gallery.wisejam.com/index.html .
However, in order to keep visitors on our own website, I have set up the gallery on a page as iframe: http://wisejam.com/gallery-2/
**Up to here, everything works fine.**

Now, where I cannot go any further is when I wish to deep link from a post/page to a certain photograph to open in the iframe.

It works perfectly as long as the visitor is ON the page (gallery-2) with the following code...

```
<a href="http://gallery.wisejam.com/featured/distortion-clear-waters-robert-schaelike.html" target="iframe_a">Distortion</a>
```

However, what I'm trying to achieve is to get the internal links to display in the iframe of the 'gallery-2', but not to have to send them to the artists' page. I wish to keep the visitors with us!

I'm sorry if this is too simple a question to ask but I'm not a professional programmer.

Many thanks for your input and help!

Comment: Are you allowed to include scripts in the third party pages? If so this can be done fairly easily. If not you have a lot of complications tracking user navigation inside the iframe due to browser security and [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: may not be so bad if you have access to files on `gallery.wisejam`. Need more understanding of what you can control and have access to

Comment: No, I have no control over gallery.wisejam, cannot include any scripts there, nothing. It's a subdomain which directs via DNS settings (A and CNAME) to wisejam.artistwebsites.com.

Comment: Short of communicating with that gallery host and seeing if they have solutions this is not an optimal situation. This type of service sounds good up front , and years ago might have worked ok in iframes but not now per link i provided and the way browsers handle cross domain issues. Alternatives would be find a more flexible third party that does allow you some script access or there are a multitude of gallery packages you can self host

Comment: I can try to communicate with the gallery host, but there must be another solution. They have something like 100,000+ artists with their own websites and problems, but a very small team to support everybody.    Don't want to go for another gallery package... this is a POD (print-on-demand) service. Very handy indeed.; not just displaying photos but actually helping to sell them.

Comment: other option is not trying to wrap in iframe. Surely they have ways to allow you to brand the gallery to make it look more like your site

Comment: They have (shopping cart widget). It's implemented here: http://wisejam.com/gallery/, but again no deep linking to single photos, or keywords search, etc. possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a php solution. It's so simple that I actually feel frustrated because it took me two days to come up with the code.

Code goes on landing page (page A) within the body:

```
  /* call iframe */
  switch($_GET['action']) {
  case 'aaa': $link="http://deeplinkAAA"; break;
  case 'bbb': $link="http://deeplinkBBB"; break;
  default: $link="http://whatever"; break;
  } 

    <iframe src="<?= $link ?>" style='border:none' width='xx' height='yy' ></iframe>
```

The links from page page B:

```
    <a href="pageA-with-above-code?action=aaa">Some Text for AAA</a>

    <a href="pageA-with-above-code?action=bbb">Some Text for BBB</a>
```

If you want to see it work:

[Pixel - Funny Palm Cat](http://wisejam.com/faa-gallery?action=pixel)

Answer (score 0):

You Write : target="iframe_a" so the photos will go to the frame you named   : name="iframe_a"  . please check it .

if you will upload the full code we will be able to give you better solution help.

Comment: Code on main page:-

<a href="http://gallery.wisejam.com/featured/distortion-clear-waters-robert-schaelike.html" target="iframe_a">Distortion</a>

    <iframe src="http://gallery.wisejam.com/" style="border:none" width="1110" height="3860" name="iframe_a"></iframe>

For the links I have tried a multitude of codes, e.g.

    <a href="#" target="iframe_a" onClick="parent.window.frames['iframe_a'].location='http://wisejam.com/?page_id=520&preview=true';this.src='http://gallery.wisejam.com/featured/distortion-clear-waters-robert-schaelike.html';return true;">Distortion</a>

None of them work!

Comment: first of all if you open style you dont need to put so many " its suppose to look like that 
:
<iframe src="gallery.wisejam.com/"; style="border:none ; width:1110px ; height:3860px ;"  name="iframe_a"></iframe>

try it

Comment: Code on the main page is... <iframe src="gallery.wisejam.com/"; style="border:none" width="1110" height="3860" name="iframe_a"></iframe> ...not more.   The other code: <a href="http://gallery.wisejam.com/featured/distortion-clear-waters-robert-schaelike.html" target="iframe_a">Distortion</a> it's just the link